# drop into python interpreter while executing function

Tags: python

i have a python module with a function:

```
def do_stuff(param1 = 'a'):
    if type(param1) == int:
        # enter python interpreter here
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_else()
```

is there a way to drop into the command line interpreter where i have the comment?  so that if i run the following in python:

```
>>> import my_module
>>> do_stuff(1)
```

i get my next prompt in the scope and context of where i have the comment in `do_stuff()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enter Interactive Mode In Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432717/enter-interactive-mode-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for 2023: `breakpoint()` is included since `py3.7` and will drop you into the debugger (`pdb` by default).

If you have other debuggers installed (`ipdb`, `pdbpp`, ... to name a few) then `breakpoint()` will instead drop you into those.

Please see these docs for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 159):

If you want a standard interactive prompt (instead of the debugger, as shown by prestomation), you can do this:

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

See: the [code module](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html#code.interact).

If you have IPython installed, and want an IPython shell instead, you can do this for IPython >= 0.11:

```
import IPython; IPython.embed()
```

or for older versions:

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
ipshell = IPShellEmbed()
ipshell(local_ns=locals())
```

Comment: for IPython>=0.11, there's no more module Shell in IPython...so start it using "import IPython; IPython.embed()" instead.

Comment: Is it possible to continue after entering `code.interact()`, a la PDB `c(ontinue)`?

Comment: `code.interact()` is a blocking call. Your program will stop and wait for it to finish. If you exit the interactive interpreter, your program should resume with the statement immediately following.

Comment: and also for bpython: `import bpython`, then `bpython.embed(locals())`

Comment: What's the difference between an interactive prompt and a debugger?

Comment: @StockB It's the *standard* interactive prompt that makes it important. The debugger is *an* interactive prompt, but it's not the same. In PDB, you cannot do multi-line statements, the built-in `help` function is overridden, etc.

Comment: To resume code execution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836061/resume-code-execution-from-code-interact-in-python

Answer (score 69):

Inserting

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

will enter the python debugger at that point

See here:
http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Comment: `pdb` is great vanilla python; if you have room for bringing in an external package, `ipdb` is great -- same functionality as the debugger, but with the syntax highlighting, tab completion, etc of ipython

Comment: Update — `ipdb` was deprecated, nowadays I use [`pdbpp` (`pdb++`)](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/), which has similar features, and works with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` (i.e. it patches that import, so it is a drop-in replacement)

Comment: @hangtwenty: why do you say `ipdb` was deprecated? I can't find any news of that.

Comment: @Kundor huh, you're right. I distinctly remember reading somewhere that the authors had decided to stop maintaining the project and pointed to another project to use instead. Maybe that happened for a bit and then it was resurrected? I could be wrong! In either case, I enjoyed `ipdb` before, but have enjoyed `pdbpp` since

Comment: One problem with this approach is that (for example) `> list([1, 2])` will not work. The debugger has a list command that takes precedence. Multiline commands (like a for loop) do not work either for me in a pdb session. Maybe some config can help that, but I am not aware of one.

Comment: @Matyas pdb lets you prefix python statements/expressions with `!` to  avoid name clashes with pdb commands. So `!list([1, 2])` will work as you expect. To enter multiline statements, you can use pdb's `interact` command, which is equivalent to `code.interact(local={**globals(), **locals()})`.

Answer (score 35):

If you want a default Python interpreter, you can do

```
import code
code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```

This will allow access to both locals and globals.

If you want to drop into an IPython interpreter, the `IPShellEmbed` solution is **outdated**. Currently what works is:

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

Comment: thanks, `code.interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))` is so much better than `code.interact(local=locals())` because the latter makes you re-import packages

Comment: This answer worked better for me since I was using a bash script to call my python code. I could not interact with my python code using the accepted answer. Thanks!