# How to pause python execution in eclipse and return to an interactive prompt

Tags: python, database, eclipse, interactive, ipython

I am using Eclipse as a Python IDE. Is there anyway for me to Debug my program and break to an interactive prompt. I am interested in exploring the existing data and running/testing commands.

I believe there has to be a way, but I am so used to compiling languages that I have not been able to find where the options are.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637198/method-to-peek-at-a-python-program-running-right-now/1637277#1637277

Comment: Possible answer for IPython: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158097/drop-into-python-interpreter-while-executing-function/2158266#2158266

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that by using PDB (Python Debugger) inside a python shell.
Look at http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html for more info.

Anyway I believe Eclipse will let you inspect you data when setting a breakpoint.

Comment: Woops that editor thingy embedded the link... Here's the url in plain text: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html