# Run python script without terminating at the end

Tags: python

Is there a command line switch to carry out the script specified without terminating the process at the end?

Windows' cmd.exe for example has the /K switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated on python's manual:

> **-i switch**
>
> When a script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add code in your script to drop into an interactive prompt. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158097/drop-into-python-interpreter-while-executing-function).

```
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

Answer (score -2):

No, it doesn't have such an options. See the [Python commandline options documentation](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html).

Depending on what you want to do, you can use a shortcut, or write a wrapper module and call the script you want to run through it with the `-m` option.