# Enter Interactive Mode In Python

Tags: python, interactive

I'm running my Python program and have a point where it would be useful to jump in and see what's going on, and then step out again. Sort of like a temporary console mode.

In Matlab, I'd use the [`keyboard`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html) command to do this, but I'm not sure what the command is in python.

Is there a way to do this?

For instance:

```
for thing in set_of_things:
    enter_interactive_mode_here()
    do_stuff_to(thing)
```

When `enter_interactive_mode()` calls, I'd like to go there, look around, and then leave and have the program continue running.

Comment: Check out the `code.InteractiveInterpreter` class and then there's always `exec`.

Comment: Could you not use breakpoints in your IDE?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`code.interact()` seems to work somehow:

```
>>> import code
>>> def foo():
...     a = 10
...     code.interact(local=locals())
...     return a
... 
>>> foo()
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> a
10
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> returns to the "main" interpreter.

You can read the locals, but modifying them doesn't seem to work this way.

Comment: In IDLE, since Ctrl+Z returns to the main interpreter instead of the program, this doesn't really work any better than sys.exit().

Comment: Another answer has an example with code.InteractiveConsole.interact() which seems to work better - it uses readline and has tab-completion. 
 ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917938/enabling-console-features-with-code-interact ). 
Ctrl+D exits the interactive session.

Comment: `CTRL-Z` puts the job to the background

Answer (score 66):

```
python -i myapp.py
```

This will execute `myapp.py` and drop you in the interactive shell. From there you can execute functions and check their output, with the whole environment (imports, etc.) of `myapp.py` loaded.

For something more sophisticated - it would be better to use a debugger like `pdb`, setting a breakpoint. Also, most IDEs (PyDev, PyCharm, Komodo...) have graphical debuggers.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question. This drops to an interactive mode after "myapp.py" finishes executing; I would like to enter an interactive mode during the exeuction of "myapp.py".

Comment: You're options are either using a debugger, or creating a script that will execute up to the point you are interested. From there on you can invoke a function to "resume" your program.

Answer (score 19):

I use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) for this purpose. I realize Emil already mentioned this in his answer, but he did not include an example or elaborate on why it answers your question.

```
for thing in set_of_things:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    do_stuff_to(thing)
```

You can read and set variables by starting your command with an exclamation point. You can also move up and down the stack (commands `u` and `d`), which `InteractiveConsole` does not have built-in mechanisms to do.

To have the program continue executing, use the `c` command. In the above example it will enter the debugger every loop iteration, so you might want to wrap the `set_trace()` call in an `if` sentence.

Comment: so basically `set_trace` gives control to the keyboard.

Answer (score 14):

You have options -- Python standard library or IPython.

The Python standard library has a [`code`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/code.html) module which has an [`InteractiveConsole`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole) class whose purpose is to "Closely emulate the behavior of the interactive Python interpreter."  This would probably be able to do what you want, but the documentation doesn't have any examples on how to use this, and I don't have any suggestions on where to go.

[IPython](http://ipython.org/), which is a more advanced Python terminal, has the option to embed a console at any point in your program built in.  According to their [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#embedding), you can simply do

```
from IPython import embed

for thing in set_of_things:
  embed()
  do_stuff_to(thing)
```

Answer (score 7):

From Python 3.7 onwards, you can also use `breakpoint()` to get into the debugger, e.g.:

```
for thing in set_of_things:
    breakpoint()
    do_stuff_to(thing)
```

This is a little easier to remember and write, and will open your code in pdb by default.

However, it's also possible to set the `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` environment to the name of a callable, which could be another debugger such as `pudb` or `ipdb`, or it could be IPython's `embed`, or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Most comfortable tool for me is [ipdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb).

> ipdb exports functions to access the IPython debugger, which features tab completion, syntax highlighting, better tracebacks, better introspection with the same interface as the pdb module.

Completion and handy introspection is especially useful for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ipdb`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb).

> To set your breakpoints, add `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` where you want to jump into the debugger. Once you reach a breakpoint, you’ll be given an interactive shell and a few lines of code around your breakpoint for context.
>
> https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/11/18/intro-python-debugger/

Comment: much better answer, since you may access local variables