# Run python script then enter interactive session in ipython

Tags: python, ipython, interactive

I have found ways to run a python script and then enter interactive mode:

- [Enter Interactive Mode In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432717/enter-interactive-mode-in-python)
- [Enabling console features with code.interact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917938/enabling-console-features-with-code-interact)

But none of them enter ipython, but rather just conventional python.

Is there a way to do the same and end up in ipython? That would give auto-complete features and color highlighting.

Comment: Duplicate indeed. Thank you. The relevant answer there is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9923008/1273751

Comment: I voted this question as a duplicate. This is the first time I do this. Will it be deleted? It would be nice to have the answer marked the question, which the OP of that post did not do.