# Resume code execution from code.interact() in Python

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7

After opening an interactive console while debugging using

```
code.interact(local=locals())
```

How can I resume code execution. I have checked the docs for the 'code' module and search stack overflow but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the same way you exit any Python interpreter session: send an end-of-file character.

That's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> Enter on Windows.

Comment: What if I want to use the standard input afterwards? (or run `code.interact` again?

Comment: OK, false alarm: the stdin shuts down when running inside PyCharm (throwing EOFError on next `code.interact`), but it works correctly on - at least some - other terminals.

Answer (score 7):

If like me you always forget to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, you can wrap up your prompt in a try/except block:

```
try:
    code.interact(local=locals())
except SystemExit:
    pass
```